# Just found an older account of mine, can they be merged?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, duplicate-user

I joined stackoverflow the other day with the ID [DevTravis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7343782/devtravis). Could these two accounts be merged, preferably the newer one being preserved and the questions from this one being migrated?

Comment: Yes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, you can use the [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link located at the footer.

Simply choose the problem (merging accounts for this case) and enter the appropriate information. Make sure to check your email for any response from Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: It has been a easier to help